# Apache Solr - Unknown Sort Order

Tags: php, drupal, solr

In my watchdog logs, I am getting the following error:
Unknown sort order: **The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect (Unknown sort order: for weddings).**

This is the var_dump of `$qry` (`$qry = new Solr_Query(`))

```
object(Solr_Query)#28 (7) { 
    ["terms"]=> NULL 
    ["keys"]=> string(31) " arts & crafts for weddings" 
    ["filters"]=> string(11) " type:frame" 
    ["sort"]=> string(14) "timestamp desc" 
    ["perpage"]=> int(24) 
    ["page"]=> int(0) 
    ["params"]=> array(0) { } 
}
```

Using Apache Tomcat/6.0.18, Drupal 6

EDIT: It seems the ampersand is causing the issue. When I remove that, there is no error. Also having quotes in the search term results in an error.

Comment: What's your query? Try to set another order param (desc, asc, top, bottom) to test.

Comment: All the information that was given to the query is above already

Comment: If you remove sort param its works?

Comment: Nope. It was actually missing it and gave an error (I'm not sure if the same error or not)

Comment: Just to be sure, try to add a space before the `timestamp desc`

Comment: timestamp field is available in response ? if it doesn't exist , it can't sort by it. Otherwise tryo to use maj => DESC

Comment: @PiLHA - tried that, no change `["sort"]=> string(16) " timestamp desc "`

Comment: @Fky - how do I check this? What is maj => DESC ? These are regular nodes in Drupal, so they all will have a timestamp, but I'm not sure how to check this in Solr

Comment: See my edit, however when I try to use htmlspecialchars, it still results in the error.